# `containerPort` and `hostPort`, which one is used by the web application internally and which one is seen by the outside?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I found the following task definiation of ECS task, which is a web application. As for `containerPort` and `hostPort`, which one is used by the web application internally and which one is used by the outside of the docker for accessing the page?

```
'taskDefinition': {
    'compatibilities': ['EC2'],
    'containerDefinitions': [{
        'portMappings': [{
            'containerPort': 4041,
            'hostPort': 4090,
            'protocol': 'tcp'}],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`containerPort` is the port that the container exposes. `hostPort` is the port you want to map it to on the host. You can use the same port on both to make things simpler.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_PortMapping.html

Comment: The EC2 will have many container instances. The user want to create the web servers before a port number can be assigned. So I want to make the host port be fixed to 443 and then assign the available container port to the web server when deploying.

Comment: You are probably looking for Dynamic Port Mapping: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/